# Code First Gerando uma chave estrangeira

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, code-first, fluent-api

tenho as seguintes classes

```
public class ControleDeVisitas
{
    public virtual ICollection<TipoDeSistemas> TipoDeSistemas { get; set; }
}

 public class TipoDeSistemas
 {
    public Guid TipoDeSistemasId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
 }
```

dessa maneira, na tabela, `TIPO DE SISTEMAS`, está sendo criado uma chave `ControleDeVisitaId`

esse é o método que eu uso para adicionar um `TipoDeSistema` ao `Controle`

```
    public ControleDeVisitasViewModel Adicionar(ControleDeVisitasViewModel controleDeVisitasViewModel, List<Guid> sistemasComerciais)
     {
var controle = Mapper.Map<ControleDeVisitas>(controleDeVisitasViewModel);
       foreach (var sistema in sistemasComerciais)
      {
        var ts = _tipoDeSistemaRepositorio.BuscarPorId(sistema);
        controle.TipoDeSistemas.Add(ts);
      }
     _controleDeVisitaRepositorio.Adicionar(controle);
     }
```

e é assim que está ficando a tebela `TipoDeSistemas`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu apaguei alguns dados, mas a verdade, é que ele ta duplicando a mesma informação, tipo, se eu escolho o sistema A,B e C.(ambos já devem estar cadastrados).

ele cria um novo sistema do tipo A, B e C na mesma tabela. e coloca a chave do Controle.

alguém sabe me informar pq que ele está criando essa chave na tabela `TipoDeSistema`?

assim está minha config:

```
 public ControleDeVisitasConfig()
    {
            ToTable("ControleDeVisitas");
            HasKey(c => c.ControleDeVisitasId);
            HasMany(c => c.TipoDeSistemas);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, neste caso o `Entity Framework` está fazendo o que foi informado a ele. Ou seja um relacionamento **1:N**.

Então, existe a necessidade de controle de visita "saber" a forma de se relacionar com muitos tipos de sistemas.